# Stereo to High Speed LED for Data Transfer

Tags: led, pwm, data

I am currently doing a project on optical data transfer using LED. The first hurdle I need to overcome is the LED driver circuit. I have little to no background in circuits. I do know a fair amount of relevant coding stuffs for this project (on the demodulation side at the receiver end)

My preliminary setup would be a stereo output from a PC and this stereo will be the input on my LED driver circuit.

The question is, how should I approach this design to achieve at least 1Mhz pulses of phosphor-based White LED's? Since the input is analog, I need an ADC so that the signal will go to some microcontroller or IC and drive the LED ON/OFF rapidly. One consideration is to have a PWM driver that can deliver at least 1Mhz pulses.

Thing that need not be considered now is 
- possibility of data that causes LED to be OFF for a noticeable period

Goal:
1. Translate a stereo input data to a high speed LED ON/OFF's sequences.
2. LED intensity should be consistent. (ie. the Photodiode that receives the light should output similar results each time assuming the data transmitted is the the same)

Comment: Have you read anything on existing methods of optical data transmission like IRdA, TOSLink, or any of the various fibre-optic transmission systems? They've been around for decades now. Also, what is the reason for using the audio port of the PC when it has so many data ports?

Comment: I have not come to those you have talked about. LED is used for various reasons. The sole reason for using the audio port is for simplicity. Assuming I only transmit songs from PC right away.

Comment: (1) Why 1MHz when the PC stereo out is band-limited to 44khz? (2) Why white (with phosphor delay) rather than pure colour (e.g. red)? (3) 'off for noticeable period' can be addressed with 8b/9b encoding, but you seem to want to reject all existing work on coding schemes?

Answer (score 1):

There is already a solution to converting stereo audio to a digital optical signal and back again that's widely used and readily available: [TOSLINK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TOSLINK). It basically is a simple conversion from the electrical S/PDIF signal to an optical format. There are many commercial chips that can convert directly between analog audio and S/PDIF (in both directions).

The only difference is that TOSLINK normally uses inexpensive plastic fiber to couple the light between the transmitter and the receiver, and you want to do a "free space" transmission. Therefore, you are going to have to focus on the optical part of the link, dealing with highly-variable signal levels and lots of potential interference.

White phosphor-based LEDs tend to have poor frequency response, mainly because of the slow decay of the phosphor's glow, although if you read datasheets carefully enough, you can find some with fast phosphors.

But you could use the slower LEDs if your receiver includes an optical filter that passes the blue light directly from the LED and ignores the yellow light from the phosphor. This might be a good idea in terms of rejecting interference anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Step by step approach

1. Get a serial ADC talking to a serial DAC so that you can feed analogue into the ADC and see it coming out of the DAC. This isn't as easy as you think because you'll have to provide both ADC and DAC with a "start of conversion" signal or something that can synchronize the two devices - remember this has to be transmitted over the optical link as well (see end of this answer for possible alternative chipset solution)
2. Duplicate this for stereo OR better still use a two channel ADC and DAC and interleave/multiplex the signals for left and right
3. Add a scrambler to the ADC serial output and add a descrambler to the DAC serial input (this overcomes the problem of AC coupling a signal that may not change for a long period of time and believe me, although you said to ignore it, you will find it necessary as soon as you try coupling via transformers or with optical devices).
4. Use a high speed coupling transformer as the first test to see it works when the dc link is broken - get it working/debug it etc..
5. Now insert the optical devices and debug - you'll probably need to spend some effort getting the optical receiver optimized and this will likely require a transconductance amplifier and maybe even a limiter circuit so that it works at non-optimum angles and at variable distances.

Good luck but if I were doing this I'd consider this chipset: -

[image]

This does the hard work of taking several inputs (ten) and combining them onto a single pair of wires which can be sent some considerable distance over copper and then deserialized into ten outputs. Obviously ADC connects on the 9205 and DAC on the 9206. Two ADCs with serial outputs take up two channels and you can use the other 8 channels for synchronization.

I use this in exactly the same application - combining ADCs and sending the data over radio or fibre. Many times I've used this with a laser to a photodiode. You don't need scrambling if you use this because the MAXIM devices insert bits into the high speed stream that keep the data toggling.

Same chipset available from TI but not the same numbers SN65LV1023 and SN65LV1224 from memory but don't quote me.

Answer (score -1):

Clock (555) + ADC + UART. There are also LED driver ICs out there, many people would just use a transistor.

Or use [two arduinos](http://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-Send-Data-by-Light-Fiber-Optics/?ALLSTEPS).

Comment: For your suggestion, I assume the flow should be Audio -> ADC -> UART -> Clock -> LED ? Since the UART converts bytes of data to sequential bits.